# makepkg freeze after installing dependencies

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, makepkg

If I try to create a package from the AUR `makepkg` seems to freeze after installing the dependencies. It just stops after installing the last dependency and freezes with 65% CPU-Usage.

Any Idea what could cause this Problem?

Comment: All AUR sources or just this one package? And which package is that?

Comment: doesn't matter which package as soon as it has dependencies it stucks after installing the last dep...

Answer (score 1):

I've found the guilty after digging through the source of `makepkg`

```
source /etc/profile &>/dev/null
```

causes the problem, if I run this command it freezes, `Ctrl+C` will kill the whole terminal.
So now I know the source of the Problem, still trying to figure out why this happens...

EDIT: Found it! I'm using `tdm` as display-manager, to start it I've put a script into `/etc/profile.d/` this Script gave back an Error `Invalid TTY`.

If you source `/etc/profile` it can't complete due to this Error.
So it was completely my fault.
Now I have to find another way of starting `TDM`

EDIT2:

just put `/usr/bin/tdm` into `~/.bash_profile` and tdm works fine.
Actually this is already in the arch-wiki, don't know why I didn't do that in the first place :-/

Comment: You want a service file to do that...

Comment: the solution was `~/.bash_profile` as mentioned in the arch-wiki. Don't know how I could overlook this! shame on me...